# Box shadow, not covering all around block in same way

Tags: html, css

I tried to cover shadow around all the blocks equally with help of CSS. I got no luck, because for some reason, one line ( the middle one ), wasn't aligning in a proper size, compared to other lines. As you can see it's thicker. I'm trying 2 days to find a solution, no luck so far.

```css
.shadow1{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width:250px; 
   height:200px; 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
   position:relative; 
}
.shadow2{
 box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width:250px; 
   height:200px; 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
   position:relative; 
}
.shadow3{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width:250px; 
   height:200px; 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
   position:relative; 
}
.shadow4{
 box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width:250px; 
   height:200px; 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
   position:relative; 
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow1"> </div>
<div class="shadow2"> </div>
<div class="shadow3"> </div>
<div class="shadow4"> </div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: What "lines" are you talking about? The shadow looks identical around each edge.

Comment: please tell me what is your problem in the box-shadow. which line of the box will appear in thick

Comment: Add the screenshot if necessary to explain clearly.

Comment: I can't see any lines,is that hidden?

Comment: Question is not clear..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well what you want exactly, but I can guess... is this what you want?

```css
.shadow1{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
   width:250px; 
 height:200px; 
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
 position:relative;
}
.shadow2{
 box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 0px 5px #ddd;
   width:250px; 
 height:200px; 
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
 position:relative; 
    margin-top:-5px;
}
.shadow3{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px #ddd;
   width:250px; 
 height:200px; 
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
    position:relative; 
    margin-top:-5px;
}
.shadow4{
 box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 0px 5px #ddd;
   width:250px; 
 height:200px; 
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
 position:relative;
     margin-top:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow1"></div>
<div class="shadow2"></div>
<div class="shadow3"></div>
<div class="shadow4"></div>
```